# How does code coverage work?

Tags: .net, test-coverage

Specifically, what is contained inside code coverage data (.nccov or xml file) and how is an html report generated by this? Does the coverage data not include the actual percentage of code covered? Is this only generated when the report is made from the coverage data? Is the coverage data sort of a guideline for the reporting process?  Do coverage files need access to assemblies to create a report?

Comment: Are you interested in how reports are generated from the code coverage data, or how this data is gathered in the first place? The title of your question being different from the body of the question, this may be why you've received the downvote.

Comment: I'm interested in how a report is generated from the code coverage data, and what kind of data is stored inside the coverage xml.

Comment: Doesn't this depend entirely on the software that generated the file(s)? If so, this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Specifically, what is contained inside code coverage data?

[Code coverage data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is used to determine how effectively your tests exercise the code in your application. This data helps you to identify sections of code not covered and sections of code partially covered by your tests, as well as sections of code where you have complete coverage. With this information, you can add to or change your test suites to maximize their effectiveness.

> Does the coverage data not include the actual percentage of code covered ?

Yes, it does show the percentage of the code that was run in each assembly, class, and method.

> Do coverage files need access to assemblies to create a report?

Yes.

Also, [check the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx) for any other related queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just have one more question, because I don't feel like I asked it very well.  Does the nccov/xml need to access the assemblies again to be converted to a html/xml?  If so, why? If the coverage percentages are inside the coverage data file (.nccov), what else does it need from the assemblies to create a report?  I'll mark your answer as the correct one, just wanted to see if you had anymore to say on this.

Comment: From what I understand once the analysis is done, they do not need to access assemblies again.